# More than one trigger does not work in WPF XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a simple button. I have two triggers, each one fades the color of the button when the mouse is either over the button or clicks the button. It works initially, but once the button is clicked, the `IsMouseOver` part of the style stops working. Only the `IsPressed` then works. The style is defined as:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
           <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
           <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border
                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                       BorderBrush="Silver"
                       BorderThickness="0.5"
                       CornerRadius="0">
                       <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                          <Trigger.EnterActions>
                             <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                   <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                             </BeginStoryboard>
                          </Trigger.EnterActions>
                          <Trigger.ExitActions>
                             <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                   <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF272727"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                             </BeginStoryboard>
                          </Trigger.ExitActions>
                       </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                             <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                   <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="DarkSlateGray"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                             </BeginStoryboard>
                          </Trigger.EnterActions>
                          <Trigger.ExitActions>
                             <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                   <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF272727"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                             </BeginStoryboard>
                          </Trigger.ExitActions>
                       </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And the button is simply defined as `<Button Margin="100,20,100,20" Background="#FF272727" Foreground="Silver">Write to index</Button>`

I have looked at some other answers but they use `MultiTrigger, and MultiDataTrigger.` I have tried those, and they either don't fix the problem or make it worse. I have also tried switching the order. It does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Exit action of the IsPressed trigger is forcing the colour and overriding the hover trigger.

Change the To value of the IsPressed Exit action to:

```
To="{x:Null}"
```

This will revert to the default colour (the one on the button itself) and allow the hover to change it again.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, this works perfectly 